# Is there any way to define color-code or color-name in html class-value?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to define color-code or color-name in HTML class-value?

```css
:root {
  --bg: "???"
}

[class*="bg["] {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="bg[#3b5998]">
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook btn-icon"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No but you can simply use inline style

```css
:root {
  --bg: "???"
}

[style*="bg"] {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button"  style="--bg:#3b5998">
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook btn-icon"></i>
</button>

<button type="button" >
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook btn-icon"></i>
</button>
```